# TFS Agent lost communication with the server

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have TFS agent runnig on Windows 10.
While trying to run build on hosted agent I get below error:

```
The agent: Agent-ABC lost communication with the server. Verify the machine is running and has a healthy network connection. For more information, see: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=846610
```

This is really frustrating since the machine is runnig fine with no network issues.

How do i resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Version: 2.141.1

Comment: Have you tried looking into the logs of the agent in the _Diag folder?
What does it say?

Comment: @Setorica log file at _Diag folder didnt create any log file for today. Strange

Comment: can you look into the latest log file. It could be that it has written to that one

Comment: @Celestial Is your agent working for DevOps or on-premise TFS? If you use on-premise TFS,  which version of TFS do you use? Do you upgrade it to the latest edition?  Please try to use the latest version of agent and try to config a new agent on this machine to see whether it works. In addition, capture both worker and agent diagnostic logs.

Comment: The latest agent for Azure DevOps Service is version 2.166.2 and the latest agent for Azure DevOps Server is 2.153.1 so you are a little behind.  It should still work though.  Just to be sure, you are trying to connect this agent from a Windows 10 machine to which version of Azure DevOps (Service or Server)